# How to generate slug from Chinese text?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to get my admin.py to read Chinese, however I do not know how can I do it. This is what I have.

> admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from collection.models import Thing


class ThingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Thing
    list_display = ('name', 'description',)
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}


admin.site.register(Thing, ThingAdmin)
```

> models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

now I can type it in English and slug will be generated properly, but when I try it in Chinese slug is blank.
[image]
[image]

any one knows how to do it?? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I just had similar problem. You need to convert chinese to text that can be stored in `SlugField`.
Include `unidecode` and optionally `slugify`:

```
from unidecode import unidecode
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
```

And overwrite save to something like this:

```
class ThingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Thing
    list_display = ('name', 'description',)
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(unidecode(self.name))
        return super(ThingAdmin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You also need to make sure `slug` will be always unique, which I do not see in your code.
It will decode name `투자` to this slug `tuja`, etc.

Comment: sorry,,sir ,,I put all those code in my admin.py,,,it did not work,,I have pip install unidecode,, or should I put those code in some where??models.py ?admin.py?? thanks for your reply

Comment: @CcL I updated class like it should be. Did you alter model ThingAdmin like that? Did you try to add new record - `save()` was called?